# Residues of $\frac{e^{iwx}}{kw^2+s}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> I am trying to find the residues of the simple poles in $$f(w)= \frac{e^{iwx}}{kw^2+s}.$$

The simples poles are at points $$w=\pm i\sqrt{\frac{s}{k}}.$$
In general, I have used the formula $$\text{Res}(f(w),w_0)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim_{w\to w_0}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\left((w-w_0)^n f(w)\right),$$ where $n$ denotes the order of the pole. However, in my particular case, I can not simplify $$\left(w-i\sqrt{\frac{s}{k}}\right)\frac{e^{iwx}}{kw^2+s}$$ to solve for the residues at each singular point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The denominator is $k(w-i\sqrt {\frac s k})(w+i\sqrt {\frac s k})$. You should be able to write down the residue using this.

Comment: I have calculated that $$\text{Res}\left(f(w),i\sqrt{\frac{s}{k}}\right)=\frac{e^{-x\sqrt{\frac{s}{k}}}}{2i\sqrt{ks}}$$ and $$\text{Res}\left(f(w),-i\sqrt{\frac{s}{k}}\right)=\frac{e^{x\sqrt{\frac{s}{k}}}}{2i\sqrt{ks}}.$$ Is this correct?

Comment: @Betty Yes, that is correct.